# Uploaded file locks after being read by GDI

Tags: c#, io, gdi

I have the following ImageObject class:

```
public class ImageObject
{
    public static Image CropImage(Image img, Rectangle cropArea)
    {
        Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(img);
        Bitmap target = new Bitmap(cropArea.Width, cropArea.Height);
        using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
        {
            g.DrawImage(bmpImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, target.Width, target.Height), cropArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            g.Dispose();
        }
        return (Image)target;
    }

    public static Image ResizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
    {
        int sourceWidth = imgToResize.Width;
        int sourceHeight = imgToResize.Height;

        float nPercent = 0;
        float nPercentW = 0;
        float nPercentH = 0;

        nPercentW = ((float)size.Width / (float)sourceWidth);
        nPercentH = ((float)size.Height / (float)sourceHeight);

        if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
            nPercent = nPercentH;
        else
            nPercent = nPercentW;

        int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
        int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);

        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight);
        //Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)b);
        using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)b))
        {
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.DrawImage(imgToResize, 0, 0, destWidth, destHeight);
            g.Dispose();    
        }
        return (Image)b;
    }

    public static void SaveJpeg(string path, System.Drawing.Image source, long quality)
    {
        EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality);
        ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");
        if (jpegCodec == null)
            return;
        EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
        encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;
        source.Save(path, jpegCodec, encoderParams);
    }

    private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(string mimeType)
    {
        // Get image codecs for all image formats
        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();

        // Find the correct image codec
        for (int i = 0; i < codecs.Length; i++)
            if (codecs[i].MimeType == mimeType)
                return codecs[i];
        return null;
    }
}
```

And I reference this code from a function in another class:

```
public static void CreateAvatar(string filepath, int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
    var big = filepath + "100x100.jpg";
    var medium = filepath + "40x40.jpg";
    var small = filepath + "25x25.jpg";
    var full_path = filepath + "avatar.jpg";
    var temp_path = filepath + "avatar_t.jpg";

    if (File.Exists(big))
    {
        File.Delete(big);
    }
    if (File.Exists(medium))
    {
        File.Delete(medium);
    }
    if (File.Exists(small))
    {
        File.Delete(small);
    }
    if (File.Exists(temp_path))
    {
        File.Delete(temp_path);
    }

    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(full_path);
    System.Drawing.Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
    System.Drawing.Size hundred = new Size(100, 100);
    System.Drawing.Size forty = new Size(40, 40);
    System.Drawing.Size twentyfive = new Size(25, 25);

    //we crop, then we resize...
    var cropped = ImageObject.CropImage(img, rect);
    ImageObject.SaveJpeg(temp_path, cropped, 100L);

    //problems usually from here. can't save big, because it can't read temp_path - it's locked...
    var resize_big = ImageObject.ResizeImage(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(temp_path), hundred);
    ImageObject.SaveJpeg(big, resize_big, 100L);

    var resize_forty = ImageObject.ResizeImage(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(temp_path), forty);
    ImageObject.SaveJpeg(medium, resize_forty, 100L);

    var resize_twentyfive = ImageObject.ResizeImage(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(temp_path), twentyfive);
    ImageObject.SaveJpeg(small, resize_twentyfive, 100L);
}
```

This method is called by a web service. On the first execution of this code (after an IIS restart), all is well, but if used again it hangs. I know it has to do with the two images I have created: `avatar.jpg` and `avatar_t.jpg`. I know this because I cannot delete or rename the images in Explorer:

[image: locked file when trying to rename]

I have ensured I have `Dispose`'d the `Graphics` objects as suggested by many, but I can't figure out why the locks won't release?  Can anyone see the problem?

Ideally, I'd like to do this at the bottom:

```
var resize_twentyfive = ImageObject.ResizeImage(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(temp_path), twentyfive);
            ImageObject.SaveJpeg(small, resize_twentyfive, 100L);

//clean up, delete avatar.jpg and avatar_t.jpg
File.Delete(temp_path);
File.Delete(full_path);
```

And delete the images I used to read from - they are no longer needed.  I don't mind them staying there, so long as I can then overwrite them at will from the uploader...

Comment: Can you check where exactly the exception is being thrown"?

Comment: On the second execution of the code, it reaches `ImageObject.SaveJpeg(temp_path, cropped, 100L);` and throws a `A generic error occured within GDI+` exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`System.Drawing.Image.FromFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4sahykhd.aspx) does not close the file until you call Dispose on the image.

[Bitmap and Image constructor dependencies](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814675):

> When either a Bitmap object or an Image object is constructed from a
>   file, the file remains locked for the lifetime of the object. As a
>   result, you cannot change an image and save it back to the same file
>   where it originated.
>
> Additionally, if the stream was destroyed during the life of the
>   Bitmap object, you cannot successfully access an image that was based
>   on a stream. For example, the Graphics.DrawImage() function may not
>   succeed after the stream has been destroyed

`Image.FromFile()` is  a very poor API method (in the sense that it sets the developer up for failure!). The problem is caused by:

> GDI+, and therefore the System.Drawing namespace, **may defer the
>   decoding of raw image bits until the bits are required by the image**.
>   Additionally, even after the image has been decoded, GDI+ may
>   determine that it is more efficient to discard the memory for a large
>   Bitmap and to re-decode later. Therefore, GDI+ must have access to the
>   source bits for the image for the life of the Bitmap or the Image
>   object.
>
> To retain access to the source bits, GDI+ locks any source file, and
>   forces the application to maintain the life of any source stream, for
>   the life of the Bitmap or the Image object.

Again, quoting from the support article:

> To work around this problem, create new Bitmap images by using one of
>   the following methods (as described later in this section):
>
> - Create a non-indexed image.
> - Create an indexed image.
>
> In both cases, calling the Bitmap.Dispose() method on the original
>   Bitmap removes the lock on the file or removes the requirement that
>   the stream or memory stay alive.

Comment: This is great Mitch and certainly explains why I have the problem. Unfortunately, it doesn't say how to fix it. Do I re-write my code not to use these APIs? Do I avoid the GDI altogether?

Comment: Ahh, sorry Mitch, seemed you were writing as I was. My mistake. Thanks for the help +1.

Comment: I added `source.Dispose()` after my `source.Save(path, jpegCodec, encoderParams);` line in `SaveJpeg()` and all was well. Massive thanks Mitch - not only did you provide the answer, you explained why the problem occured :)  Many thanks.